# Traer valores de Select donde ambos coincidad MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select

Tengo lo siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM metadatas WHERE value IN ('Monumento', 'Arquitectura')
```

Despues de hacer esa consulta me trae varios resultados, pero necesito traer donde ambos coincidan. El resultado seria el siguiente:

### id - name - value

1 - Iglesia - Arquitectura

1 - iglesia - Monumento

2 - Casa minimalista - Arquitectura

El resultado que busco es:

### id - name - value

1 - Iglesia - Arquitectura

1 - iglesia - Monumento

Debido a que Casa minimalista no Tiene un value Monumento.

Comment: `SELECT iglesia FROM ..........`

Comment: podrias probar con algo como esto: SELECT * FROM metadatas WHERE value = 'Arquitectura' OR value ='Monumento' GROUP BY value

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero busco es que aparezca solamente los resultados donde ambos coincidan. No me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

primero tienes que validar que exista dos registros para cada NAME , y al último colocas la misma validación que has usado.

```
SELECT * FROM metadatas2 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM 
               (SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT(*) CANT FROM metadatas2
                GROUP BY ID,NAME)A
             WHERE CANT=2) 
AND  value IN ('Monumento', 'Arquitectura')
```

Espero te sirva
Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por responder pero me sigue trayendo los mismos dos resultados.

Comment: @Arielperez lo acabo de probar y no trae los dos resultados es raro